# Uploading to azure storage returning an empty file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

My upload works the following way:

1. I have two methods, one that resize the image and the other one uploads the full image size.
2. My upload method works fine because I can find it inside my blobs the problems comes when I try to download the complete image it returns a size 0 file but the resized image works just fine.

Here is some context:

```
public async Task<UserProfile> PostProfilePictureAsync(int userId, IFormFile file)
    {
        var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
        var name = file.FileName;
        var thumbName = "resized_"+file.FileName;

        var resizedStream = ResizeImage(stream);
        var uploadedFileUrl = await UploadFileAsBlob(stream, name);
        var uploadedResizedUrl = await UploadFileAsBlob(resizedStream, thumbName);

        var entity = await _context.UserProfile.FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.userId == userId);
        entity.PictureUrl = uploadedFileUrl;
        entity.ThumbnailUrl = uploadedResizedUrl;
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Mapper.Map<UserProfile>(entity);

    }

private Stream ResizeImage(Stream stream) {
        MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream();
        // Create a new image 
        var image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        // Set the image size for the final size values
        var resizedImage = new Bitmap(80, 80);
        // Draw the image inside a new graphic container
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage);
        g.DrawImage(image,0,0,80,80);
        // Save that new image and return the stream
        result.Position = 0;
        resizedImage.Save(result,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        result.Position = 0;
        return result;
    }

private async Task<string> UploadFileAsBlob(Stream stream, string filename)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials("my_credentials", "my_key"), true);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("my_reference");
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
        await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
        stream.Dispose();
        return blockBlob?.Uri.ToString();
    }
```

Anyone knows where I made a mistake, I sense I might need to separate the uploadToBlob because its causing errors with the stream. Any help would be appreciated. Here are some images for reference:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens if you try to `stream.Position = 0;` after calling `ResizeImage()`? It seems that as the stream is already consumed, it's uploaded empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As  Camilo Terevinto mentioned that you need to set `stream.Position = 0;` after calling ResizeImage(). Then it should work correctly for you.

```
var resizedStream = ResizeImage(stream);
stream.Position = 0 //add this code.
var uploadedFileUrl = await UploadFileAsBlob(stream, name);
```